# How to clear Bonjour cache programmatically on iPad?

Tags: ios, bonjour

I'm having a strange behaviour with the Bonjour service discovery on the iPad.

My code which probably is not the best yet, sometimes is not able to discover a bonjour service.

For this conclusion I had my Macbook open at my side with a little app called Bonjour explorer, and a small app on a Windows XP PC which is a Bonjour service.

First I had to struggle with Windows XP side, which also seems an enemy for Bonjour services. But when it was getting discovered all the time by the Macbook app, the same was not happening on the iPad side.

My question is:

Is there any recommend way of establishing a connection with a Bonjour service using the iOS API?

Comment: We have a similar problem with iOS. What we've found is that sometimes when you connect to a Wifi iOS doesn't repopulate the Bonjour cache. We are able to force this by manually turning the Wifi off for a few seconds then back on, but I don't know of a way of doing this programatically. This seems to be endorsed by Apple:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1310/_index.html

Comment: does rebooting the device okay?